# Prevent submitted form from opening in same popup

Tags: html, post, popup, forms

My code: `<form method='post' target='_blank'`... I have multiple of these forms on my page with the same `action` attribute.

Problem: Only one popup ever opens. If a second form is submitted, it replaces the first form's popup.

How do I get a new popup for each form? (Preferably without changing the `action` attribute.)

**EDIT:** I tried adding a random number (`Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)`) as a `null` parameter in the `action` url. This still opens in the same popup.

**NOTE:** There is no JS being used. However, I'd accept a JS answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete working code :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function popup(form) {
    var popup_id = 'popup_'+form.id
    window.open(form.action, popup_id, 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = popup_id;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="page.php" onsubmit="popup(this); return false;">

<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>

<form id="form2" action="page.php" onsubmit="popup(this);return false;">

<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Identical behavior. :(

Comment: Then something else is causing "unexpected" behavior. How are your generating your popup ?

Comment: It's just when the user submits the form.

Comment: I'm not using any JS here.